# Using Version Control but still access the files normal way

Tags: php, linux, version-control

I am trying hard to use version control but i am so used to old method of editing files directly via FTP that i am feeling confused what to do. So i am thinking of one solution and please help me with this if its possible or not

I have the user folder in Linux VPS system(Single VPS only)

`/home/user/public_html2`

Now that will be linked with  `Http://demo.server.com`.
That directory will be version controlled with `repo` in the folder `/usr/bin/repo/` so that i can commit the changes.

Now i will have another directory called

`/home/user/public_html` which will have the contents updated as the commit is done in `/home/user/public_html2`.

That `/home/user/public_html` will be linked with `http://main.server.com`

So that i keep working and editing files in public_html2 via FTP normal and test code as it is but main site is version controlled

Is it possible??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using a version control system, why do you need to of to a FTP location to edit the files... It defeats the whole purpose.
Rather, checkout the files from the repository into your local machine and after the changes are done, commit the code.
If you don't want to use the version while working with the files on your local, simply export the code instead of checkout.

The problem I see from your approach is that the files / directories may go out of sync. Also, if there are multiple users working then this approach would bomb.

I would suggest to have the working copy of the files in your local machine and use them instead of mirroring them to another folder.

Comment: My problem is that i have to work from 5 diff location or may be more and my internet connection is very very slow , so i cant always kepp the local copy of all the files on local computer. so i need to work via FTP so that i can work via any website which support FTP editing

Comment: I believe if you are working from 5 different locations (Machines), a checkout at each one of them at the very first time will be a painful but fruitful activity. So then next time u change the location, just fire an update and your local copy will be up to date within minutes.  I still don't see any rationale behind using both FTP and Version Control.

Comment: But how will i use checkout on location or computer where i don't have any version control installed. that was reason i want to use because usually FTP is everywhere installed and i  not i have the webiste where i have my ftp accounts and i can edit files from internet. if i don't have multiple developers will my system work

Comment: What you can do is that put a wrapper on the Source Server, where all the files are placed to commit all the changes into version control system at the end of the day. Now, checkout a local copy of your files on the main server (Which you will access thru FTP) and modify them via the regular FTP channel. And at the end of the day all the changes will be committed into the repository via the wrapper script. See, the basic fundamentals of version control says that you should not modify (touch) the files directly once they are in the repo. Use to working copy and commit the changes!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's possible. But once you start to use version control systems, you should keep accessing your version controlled files through that system. 
Or better, if you want to access files in "normal way" as you said, then if you access that files without committing any change then it should be ok. But if you want to modify them, you should always pass through your version control system, otherwise you could have problem with file versions.

Answer (score 2):

You need a deployment script. Create a script to upload the files to the appropriate locations. Run this script whenever you wish to see your changes reflected on the site. If you wish to maintain two separate locations on a server running different versions, simply add a command line argument to the script to choose which location to upload to.

Use rsync instead of FTP if you can, to avoid transferring unchanged files every time.